# Weighted average for each row of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, weighted-average

We have a dataframe df defined as such:

```
t = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "id": ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"],
    "A": [1, 4, 6, 12],
    "B": [5, 8, 3, 6],
    "C": [9, 14, 7, 10],
}
)
```

Then I have a list:

```
weight = [2, .5, 1]
```

I need to create a new column "WMean" giving for each row the weighted average where column A has a weight 2, column B a weight .5, and column C a weight 1. Weight does not have to be a list. It can have another type.

I would need the **fastest** way to do it.

The result is:

```
id  |  A | B |  C | WMean
id1 |  1 | 5 |  9 |  3.857142857142857
id2 |  4 | 8 | 14 |  7.428571428571429
id3 |  6 | 3 |  7 |  5.857142857142857
id4 | 12 | 6 | 10 | 10.571428571428571
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`numpy.average`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.average.html) with filtered columns by list:

```
weight = [2, .5, 1]
cols = ['A','B','C']

t['WMean'] = np.average(t[cols], weights=weight, axis=1)
print (t)
    id   A  B   C      WMean
0  id1   1  5   9   3.857143
1  id2   4  8  14   7.428571
2  id3   6  3   7   5.857143
3  id4  12  6  10  10.571429
```

Comment: @Ch3steR - I try test, but I think it is slowier.

Comment: `In [228]: %timeit t['WMean1'] = np.average(t[cols], weights=weight, axis=1)
1.88 ms ± 191 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [229]: %timeit t['WMean2'] = t[cols].agg(np.average, axis=1, weights=weight)
1.79 s ± 18.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: @Ch3steR - tested for 40k rows `t = pd.concat([t] * 10000, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: @Ch3steR - ya, I think reason is `agg` iterate by rows, so slow.

Comment: Yes, I guess it's applying `np.average` on each row.